Does retarded Newtonian gravity predict apsidal precession and gravitational radiation?
This is a question that have troubled me for a while, beginning with the historical fact that the apsidal precession of Mercury as noted by Urbain Le Verrier was one of the motivating issues behind Einstein’s attempts to formulate a theory of gravity. By a retarded model of gravity, I mean a model where changes to the gravitational potential propagate with a finite velocity $v = v_0$ instead of being infinite $v = \infty$, that is doing a retarded time transformation
$$t \mapsto t_r = t - \displaystyle\frac{\|r – r’\|}v.$$
A retarded Newtonian model thus uses an inverse square law for the force field, under a retarded time transformation.
With gravitational radiation I mean the constant loss of energy and (angular) momentum in an $n$-body system, $n \geq 2$. In general relativity, this “radiation” is known as gravitational waves.
I have tried some inconclusive numerical simulations. I first wrote a simulator in Python, but since I have to store the previous positions of all particles it is unbearably slow. I then rewrote all the code in C, but it is still slow and I don’t know it the “precession” I am getting is due to numerical errors (and a finite discretization of time) or not. It also seems to me that angular momentum and linear momentum are not being preserved in these simulations, but again this could be numerical errors.
Ideally you would want a theory that respects various invariances and conservation laws, and I am curious if there have been any attempts to explain apsidal precession and gravitational radiation without invoking general relativity.

It is certainly not true that just adding retardation can explain Mercury's perihelion precession, because those calculations are always done in the frame where the Sun is at rest.

This problem is famously covered in Feynman lectures, that Nature cooks up solutions to problems in ways that the human brain simply doesn't expect. The "centre of gravity" would not be where the retarded position is, but rather has a correction for the retarded linear velocity. There were some theorems people proved that showed that the retarded position's pull would violate energy conservation. In the end, all those theorems are useless because Nature chose a different way to circumvent them all.

As for numerical issues, you cannot even begin to start talking about all these precession stuff until you have an integrator good enough to show the difference. You had better have something that actually conserves all the conserved quantities when you haven't added the complications.

@knzhou not sure what you mean by "those calculations". Numerical calculations can take motions into account, and if we try to formulate such calculations for retarded gravity, motion of the Sun would have to be taken into account. Without motion of the Sun, retardation can have no effect.

This paper may be of interest: Michal Křížek, Numerical experience with the finite speed of gravitational interaction, Math. Comput. Simulation 50 (1999), 237 - 245. MR 2000h:85003. -- https://doi.org/10.1016/S0378-4754(99)00085-3

Křížek says introduction of delay breaks simple periodic motions, the orbital motion perifocus rotates, and orbits expand.

First off:
As pointed out in the comment section: the perihelion precession of the orbit of Mercury is unrelated to the speed at which change of potential propagates.

Recommended reading: Steven Carlip (1999), Aberration and the speed of gravity.
Even if you were to skip all the mathematical expressions, Carlip discusses the physical interpretation, and that is already very informative.

If you take newtonian gravity and you have change of the potential propagate with finite velocity, without any other modification, then quantities such as energy, momentum and angular momentum will not be conserved.
Laplace used that to put a lower limit on the speed of propagation of gravity. Steven Carlip writes: "By analyzing the motion of the Moon, Laplace concluded in 1805 that the speed of (Newtonian) gravity must be at least $7 \times 10^6 c$" (P. S. Laplace, A treatise in Celestial Mechanics).
The first to comment on how to formulate a theory of gravity that is Lorentz invariant (hence finite speed of propagation) was Henri Poincaré, in 1905. What is necessary is that the theory of gravity must contain terms that are velocity dependent, in such a way that quantities such as energy, momentum and angular momentum are conserved.

The Coulomb force is described as mediated by a field. (For a discussion of the various terms in the expression that describes the effect Steven Carlip refers to the Feynman Lectures, Volume II, chapter 21) The nature of the interaction is such that effect of relative velocity is to some extent canceled out by a velocity dependence of the interaction. As is well known: charged particles that go around in a particle accelerator emit electromagnetic radiation. The cancelation is not complete, with electromagnetic radiation carrying off the difference. (Depending on the energy regime that emission is referred to as cyclotron radiation or synchrotron radiation.)
In the case of gravitational interaction as described by GR: emission of gravitational waves is far less than in the case of the electromagnetic interaction. For gravity there is a greater level of cancelation. The difference is at a fundamental level. The difference in extent of cancelation correlates with the fact that electromagnetic interaction is a vector field interaction, and gravitational interaction is a tensor field interaction.

"The nature of the interaction is such that effect of relative velocity is to some extent canceled out by a velocity dependence of the interaction." What exactly is meant by this?

Yes, retarded Newtonian gravity predicts an apsidal precession. I have shown it through an analytical solution of the relevant orbital equations in this paper . Applied to the solar system planets one obtains the following precession for the planets

The precession is mainly determined by the eccentricity of the orbit (left column of the table), with smaller contributions due to the finite size of the Sun (middle column) and the Sun's rotation (right column).
Mercury has the largest precession with about -0.3 arcsec/century (i.e. retrograde). This is all assuming the speed of gravity to be equal to the speed of light.
I don't see though how you could generate gravitational radiation within Newtonian physics (retarded or not).
